# iOS 11 - Navigation Bar loading with half height during push transition

Tags: height, navigationbar, ios11, xcode9

Since updating from Xcode 8.3 to 9, I'm seeing this weird behaviour that during push transition the target controller's Navigation Bar is loading with half height first and then settling with correct height.
Happening on all the screens of different navigation controllers. 
Tried enable/disable nav bar translucent, and Safe Area Layout Guides but of no help. Happening only on iOS 11. For new view controllers too.

[Screencast showing this behaviour.](https://youtu.be/P76fXhqugj0)

Comment: I am having same problem. Have you found the fix yet?

Comment: @TungVoDuc Check my answer below. I'd suggest look out for other (third-party) sources impacting your push transition.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that I'm using an old version of [KMNavigationBarTransition](https://github.com/MoZhouqi/KMNavigationBarTransition) library that uses [method swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) to manage navigation bar style during push transition. Update of this library fixed the issue.

Comment: This is exactly what I had. Thansk!